# Add InitParam to silverlight object, from Code/Javascript/jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, silverlight, parameter-passing

Is there a way, to change initParam parameter, on my silverlight object, from my code?
Can't jQuery do this, somehow?

I have my silverlight object, in a div that is display:none, and before I show it, I would like to add some InitParams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would take in this case is just to leave a place hold `<div />` where I want to put the Silverlight object.  Include in the page the [Silverlight.j](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838126%28VS.95%29.aspx#createobject)s file and use the createObject() method to create the plugin along with all its properties and initParams when necessary.

Comment: I've done this, but I can't get it to work. I've made a javascript function, that calls createObject. I have then put the function in the OnClientClick on a linkbutton. The function goes through, without errors, yet no silverlight gets loaded.

Comment: It helps when I stop mispelling the target div :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. The following provides the code with server controls rather than a JQuery.

You can add the initParam attribute in the object tag of your aspx page where yout silverlight app is hosted like below.

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication3.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      **<param name="initparams" id="initParams" runat="server" value="key=value"/>**
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0"
```

in the same aspx page you can have an event where it sets the values for the param like below

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    initParams.Attributes.Add("value",  TextBox1.Text);
}
</script>
```

Then you can access the value of the initParams in the App Startup code in the silverlight application like below.

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.InitParams.ContainsKey("param"))
            MessageBox.Show(e.InitParams["param"]);
```

Make sure you provide the value for the initParams in the following format and also check in the code for the existance of the key.

```
key1=value1, key2=value2
```

Alternatively, you can use the Silverlight.createObject and pass the initParameters as well
Refer to the link
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.